# Upon Dynamically Adding content using Ajax, Menu dropdown not working

Tags: jquery

trying to add contents dynamically to the menu from Ajax and json using the For Each loop

```
var menuContent = "";
$.each(parseData1, function(idx, obj) {

menuContent += "some HTML tags and classes";
menuContent += obj.val;
menuContent += "some HTML tags and classes";

}); 
$('#MegaMenuId').append(menuContent);
```

Comment: What do you mean by _menu dropdown not working_?

Comment: it is suppose to display submenus in the form of dropdown. when the content is statically added it will display dropdown on hover. but when the content is added dynamically using ajax. it doesnt work. I've checked in firebug. the content is added as it was statically.

Comment: Show us the `html` after you have appended the content to the `MegaMenuId`.